# Watchman com.github.facebook.watchman.plist: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, facebook, ember.js, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I was trying to use watchman with [Ember-CLI](https://ember-cli.com/) and despite having it installed I got `"Could not find watchman"` error. After that I tried to run watchman manually and got this error:

```
$ watchman watch some_directory
/Users/piotrpalek/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist: Operation not permitted
1417520511: tid=2122277632 unable to talk to your watchman!
```

I am using `OSX Yosemite` and installed watchman via `Homebrew`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything.. but I didn't restart my macbook before trying everything. I guess that's a lesson for the future since restarting my mac did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to restart your terminal.